# Need help finding coding error in my PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to prepare an SQL UPDATE command for an edit page for an internal (yes I'm aware I'm not coding in current version PHP - work needed a quick fix and its an internal system - please don't judge me!) database and no matter what I seem to do, I am continually facing an error where I'm being told I have an extra ; in my statement.

However, the UPDATE command I'm about to post is almost identical (barring a few fields) to another I have prepared for an almost identical part of the database elsewhere, and that works perfectly!

I'll actually post the entire block of code, rather than just the UPDATE statement, just in case.

```
<?php
require("header.php");
$error_feat_id = "";
$valid_feature = "";
$error_feat_id = "";
$refferal_feat_id = $_GET['feat_id'];
if(isset($refferal_feat_id) == TRUE) {
    if(is_numeric($refferal_feat_id) == FALSE) {
        $error_feat_id = 1;
    }
    if($error_feat_id == 1) {
        header("Location: ".$config_basedir);
    }
    else {
        $valid_feature = $refferal_feat_id;
    }
}
else {
    $valid_feature = 0;
}

if($_POST['submit']) {
    $datereceived = $_POST['calendaryear']."-".$_POST['calendarmonth']."-".$_POST['calendarday'];
    $director1dob = $_POST['director1year']."-".$_POST['director1month']."-".$_POST['director1day'];
    $director2dob = $_POST['director2year']."-".$_POST['director2month']."-".$_POST['director2day'];
    $update_feature_sql = "UPDATE features SET Title = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."', 
    DateReceived = STR_TO_DATE(".$datereceived.", '%Y-%m-%d'), 
    Synopsis = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['synopsis'])."', 
    LogLine = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['logline']."', 
    StrandID = ".$_POST['programstrand'].", 
    CompCatID = ".$_POST['compcat'].", 
    PremiereID = ".$_POST['premierestatus'].", 
    FirstFeatureID = ".$_POST['firstfeature'].", 
    OriginID = ".$_POST['origin'].", 
    RoughtCutID = ".$_POST['roughcut'].", 
    ScreenerID = ".$_POST['screener'].", 
    Director1 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['director1'])."', 
    Director1Bio = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['director1bio'])."', 
    Director1Nationality = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['director1nation'])."', 
    Director1DOB = STR_TO_DATE(".$director1dob.", '%Y-%m-%d'), 
    Director2 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['director2'])."', 
    Director2Bio = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['director2bio'])."', 
    Director2Nationality = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['director2nation'])."', 
    Director2DOB = STR_TO_DATE(".$director2dob.", '%Y-%m-%d'), 
    Country1 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country1'])."', 
    Country2 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country2'])."', 
    Country3 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country3'])."', 
    Country4 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country4'])."', 
    Country5 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country5'])."', 
    Country6 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country6'])."', 
    Country7 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country7'])."', 
    Country8 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country8'])."', 
    Country9 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country9'])."', 
    Country10 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country10'])."', 
    Cast1 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cast1'])."', 
    Cast2 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cast2'])."', 
    Cast3 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cast3'])."', 
    Cast4 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cast4'])."', 
    AdditionalComments = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['additionalcomments'])."', 
    DurationHours = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['durationhours'])."', 
    DurationMins = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['durationmins'])."', 
    ScreeningFormat1 = ".$_POST['screeningformat1'].", 
    ScreeningFormat2 = ".$_POST['screeningformat2'].", 
    ScreeningFormat3 = ".$_POST['screeningformat3'].", 
    ScreeningFormat4 = ".$_POST['screeningformat4'].", 
    ScreeningFormat5 = ".$_POST['screeningformat5'].", 
    DCPEID = ".$_POST['dcpe'].", 
    DCPCPL = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dcpcpl'])."', 
    SubTypeID = ".$_POST['subtype'].", 
    AspectID = ".$_POST['aspect'].", 
    LanguageID = ".$_POST['language'].", 
    SubtitlesID = ".$_POST['subtitles'].", 
    AudioID = ".$_POST['audio'].", 
    PubRecID = ".$_POST['pubrec'].", 
    TypeOfMaterials = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['typeofmaterials'])."', 
    ContactName = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contactname'])."', 
    ContactEmail = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contactemail'])."', 
    ContactPhone1 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contactphone1'])."', 
    ContactPhone2 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contactphone2'])."', 
    ContactAddress = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contactaddress'])."', 
    HomeAddressID = ".$_POST['homeaddress'].", 
    ContactWebsite = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contactwebsite'])."', 
    SAERecID = ".$_POST['saerec'].", 
    SAERetID = ".$_POST['saeret'].", 
    FeeStatusID = ".$_POST['feestatus'].", 
    EntryFeeID = ".$_POST['entryfee'].", 
    ProdYearID = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prodyear'])."', 
    ProdCo1 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prodco1'])."', 
    ProdWebsite1 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prodwebsite1'])."', 
    ProdCo1Nation = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prodco1nation'])."', 
    ProdCo2 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prodco2'])."', 
    ProdWebsite2 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prodwebsite2'])."', 
    ProdCo2Nation = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prodco2nation'])."', 
    Producer1 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['producer1'])."', 
    Producer1Nation = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['producer1nation'])."', 
    Producer2 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['producer2'])."', 
    Producer2Nation = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['producer2nation'])."', 
    Producer3 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['producer3'])."', 
    Producer3Nation = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['producer3nation'])."', 
    Producer4 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['producer4'])."', 
    Producer4Nation = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['producer4nation'])."', 
    SalesAgent = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['salesagent'])."', 
    Distributor = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['distributor'])."', 
    TalentAttached = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['talentattached'])."', 
    PreviouslyScreenedAt = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prevscreenat'])."', 
    ScreeningFeesID = ".$_POST['screeningfees'].", 
    ScreeningFeesAmt = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['screeningfeesamt'])."', 
    KidsID = ".$_POST['kids'].",
```

Code showing error on this line

```
ConfirmID = ".$_POST['confirm']." WHERE ID = ".$refferral_feat_id.";"; 


mysql_query($update_feature_sql) or die(mysql_error());
header("Location: ".$config_basedir."feat_show.php?feat_id=".$refferal_feat_id);
}
else {
    $sql_get_feature = "SELECT * FROM features WHERE ID = ".$refferal_feat_id.";";
    $query_get_feature = mysql_query($sql_get_feature);
    $rows_get_feature = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_get_feature);
?>
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting there is rather suggestive, don't you think? :)

Comment: What is the value of ConfirmID supposed to be?

Comment: are you getting a PHP syntax error, or an SQL one?

Comment: @JonnyS - ConfirmID is an int value passed by a dropdown
MarcB - I'm getting a PHP error - specifically a syntax error on Line 109 (The ConfirmID) line. 
I have attempted the below corrections and nothing seems to work. If anything, it just seems to transfer the error to line 111 and beyond.

Answer (score 1):

That first line in your second code block has 5 double quotes.  Your string isn't terminated.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a continuation of the first block, with OP's commentary stuffed in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

well, it does look like you have an extra ; have you tried?

```
ConfirmID = $_POST['confirm']." WHERE ID = ".$refferral_feat_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems wrong

```
ConfirmID = ".$_POST['confirm']." WHERE ID = ".$refferral_feat_id.";";
```

try changing it in:

```
ConfirmID = $_POST['confirm']." WHERE ID = ".$refferral_feat_id;
```

Comment: It can't be this correction, as the string has started many lines above and I am using double quotes to break out the PHP variables I want inputted to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok taking into consideration that ConfirmID is part of the string being defined above it.

```
.$_POST['kids'].", ConfirmID = ".$_POST['confirm']." WHERE ID = ".$refferral_feat_id;
```

I believe the below line should work.  SQL queries passed to mysql_query() do not end in a semicolon.

```
ConfirmID = ".$_POST['confirm']." WHERE ID = ".$refferral_feat_id;
```